# uTorrent repeatedly downloads old files from the RSS feed

Tags: rss, utorrent

So I set up uTorrent to automatically download torrents from EZTV search-based RSS feeds. And it works splendidly.

I just set feeds to download automatically, and didn't set up smart episode filters or anything else in the uTorrent itself.

However, from time to time something happens to EZTV feeds which makes uTorrent re-download every single torrent in every feed.

I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: interesting, never seen this, but then again I only download a few shows,  not every single one.  I'm not sure how this Q will stand due to it being about piracy too...

Comment: Questions about torrents are fine, so long as it's not explicitly about anything that may be illegal. But this is leaning toward a website support issue since it's the EZTV feed that's the problem here.

Comment: Do you delete the shows after they're done? I've never noticed this, but I don't delete things after.

Comment: Phoshi, this happens whether I delete the show afterwards or not; the only difference is that if I didn't delete it, it gets seeded again if I removed it from the list.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**smart episode filter**](http://www.utorrent.com/documentation/rss), so it only downloads one of each episode.

That's what it's designed for.

> Smart ep. filter makes µTorrent only
>   download the first version of each new
>   episode that matches your filter. This
>   function will only work if the
>   "Episode" column is not blank."Episode" column is not blank.